# User Control Tells Project What To Do

Tags: c#, winforms, class, project, user-controls

This might be abit "out there", but here goes:

I have a User Control. And I have a project. How can I have my user control pass a particular "event" to my project, and then have my project run that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UserControl

```
        public delegate void BigEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public event BigEventHandler SomeThingBigHappened;


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnSomeThingBigHappened(e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnSomeThingBigHappened(EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeThingBigHappened(this, e);
        }
```

In your form

```
 private void userControl11_SomeThingBigHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something Really Really big happened in Usercontrol!!");
        }
```

You will need to bind the usercontrol event in form designer, and in control, instead of button1_click, make the `OnSomeThingBigHappened(e);`call where the event will occur

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! I thought it was a stupid question and that it couldn't be done.